# Link error when switching from 64-bit to 32-bit openCV

Tags: opencv

I've been successfully using OpenCV 3.3.0 in VS 2017 in 64-bit mode. I now need to switch to 32-bit mode. I installed and compiled the 32-bit version of OpenCV 3.4.3 ([by meticulously following this link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html)) I set all properties:
o   Copy opencv_world343.dll and opencv_world343d.dll from …\openCV_3.4.3\opencv_build\install\x86\vc15\bin  into the project directory and also to the x86\ Release and Debug directories (after they will be created then the project is complied)
o   In the Solution Explorer right click on the top level project directory and go to properties-> C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directories  and add ...\openCV_3.4.3\opencv_build\install\include and click apply
o   Then go to properties-> Linker -> General -> Additional library directories and add ...\openCV_3.4.3\opencv_build\install\x86\vc15\lib and apply
o   Then go to properties-> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies and add “opencv_world343.dll” for release mode and “opencv_world343d.dll” for debug mode.

I'm still getting a linker error "invalid or corrupt file: can not read at 0x390" pointing to opencv_world343d.dll in debug mode, same error in release mode pointing to opencv_world343.dll

Is this a bug in 3.4.3 OpenCV of am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, never mind, I found the problem: the settings in the Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies should point to opencv_world343.lib, not to opencv_world343.dll

Comment: Can you do so please?

Comment: and how do I do it?